# Error with implementing a Binary Tree in C++

Tags: c++, class, binary-tree

I try to write a new BinaryTree class with a few basic methods but my test program doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point out what's wrong with the code?

The program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    BinaryTree example;
    example.insertNode(1);
    cout << example.height() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a debugger to step through your code line by line so you can see what's happening.

Comment: `if (root == NULL) { root->data = data;}` ??? You need to create the root node first: `{ root = new TreeNode; root->data = data;}`

Comment: Also, initialize `left` and `right` to `nullptr` in TreeNode's definition, and use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Never in any of this code do you ever actually *allocate* a `TreeNode`. I think you should review whatever tutorial or course material you're learning this from, because dynamic allocation is mandatory for a dynamic tree, sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `node` isn't even allocated a memory. The code

```
if (root == NULL) {
        root->data = data;
    }
```

should first be changed to

```
if (root == NULL) {
       // Allocate memory to root
        root->data = data;
    }
```

In this code

```
int BinaryTree::height(TreeNode* node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
    }
}
```

your tree has only 1 element as a result of `example.insertNode(1);`

so the execution will come to `else` part

here you're doing

`return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));`

without checking if `node->left` or `node->right` exists or not. Also, since you haven't initialized `node->left` and `node->right` with `NULL/nullptr` value, it contains garbage which leads to unexpected result

Comment: "since you haven't initialized node->left and node->right" - or even `node`. Nowhere in the OP's post is a `TreeNode` ever actually allocated, much less properly initialized.